# How to use the gem whenever?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, whenever

I'm trying to use the gem whenever to plan some tasks of my application, but it doesn't work. Nothing happen. I tried to make it run every minutes to make sure that was working but it's not.
If you have any ideas of where is my problem it will be great.

I want to run a rake task every day at the same time :

schedule.rb :

```
set :environment, "development"
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}

every 1.day, :at => '8:00 pm' do
  rake "rake set:friends"
end
```

Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'whenever', :require => false
```

When I run `whenever` in my term, I have :

```
0 20 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/orsay/my_application &&   RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake rake set:friends --silent >>  log/cron_log.log 2>> log/cron_error_log.log'

## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
```

The message above tell me that my task is recorded well in cron tab. So why nothing happen ?

Comment: Did you check the cron logs?

Comment: Yes the logs tells me : `Jul 15 15:44:01 orsay-EasyNote-TK85 CRON[11552]: (orsay) CMD (/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/orsay/inch-test && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake import:buildings --silent >> log/cron_log.log 2>> log/cron_error_log.log')`

So it seems to be working, but when I check my database nothing have been imported.

Comment: Try to run the rake task manually, and check everything works fine.. and then run it with cron..

Comment: Already did. All works fine without whenever and cron tab. It's why I do not understand why it doesn't work with.